# Windows Azure Web Sites unusable and shows a red exclamation mark in Management Portal

Tags: azure

Windows Azure Web Sites shows a red exclamation mark and when I hover over the exclamation mark I see 'The portal cannot load the management data for this resource type'. I am not able to click on Web Sites to add new web sites. I am able to manage other azure resources such as Cloud Services.

Any ideas on what could be causing this and how to rectify would be great.

EDIT:  I have tried CTRL+F5, F5, signing out and back in and trying again after 24 hours and different browsers and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft about this and eventually they solved the problem. There was nothing that I could do, it was something they needed to fix on their side.

Comment: The downvote here is funny. I asked the question. I contacted Microsoft. They fixed it and told me it was something that they had incorrectly configured when making a related change, nothing to do with what I had done. That is the answer to the question that I originally asked. Other questions that are helpful to other people deserve the upvotes, but this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 6):

This happens from time to time with all the services. Just refresh the portal (Ctrl+F5) and shall be OK. Usually happens on slow internet connections, but I've seen this behavior on a decent speed also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I have tried CTRL+F5, F5, signing out and back in and trying again after 24 hours and different browsers and the problem still occurs.